# Suppose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$ and $x \neq L$. Prove there is some $N$ such that $a_n \neq x$ for all $n>N$.

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Suppose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$ and $L \neq x$. Prove there is some $N$ such that $a_n \neq x$ for all $n > N$.

We know by the definition of convergence of a sequence, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists\ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$, $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$.

I try to chose $\epsilon = \frac{\left|L\right|}{2}$ and then:

1. If $L<x$ we have $L+\frac{|L|}2=\frac{L}2<x.$ Hence for all $n\ge N$, $a_n<x$.
2. If $L>x$ we have $L-\frac{|L|}2=\frac{L}2>x.$ Hence for all $n\ge N$, $a_n >x$.

Is it right?

Comment: $L+\frac{|L|}2=\frac{L}{2}?$ That’s true if $L<0,$ but not necessarily just because $L<x.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think it's only if $x=0$ but I don't know how to continue

Comment: It's easier to choose $\epsilon = |L-x|$.

Comment: Duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942879/suppose-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-a-n-l-and-l-neq-0-prove-there-is?rq=1)

Comment: Choosing $\epsilon$ as $\frac{|L|}2$ is not a good idea. Because if $x=\frac34L$, then $|x-L|<\epsilon$! Instead, let $\epsilon=\frac{|L-x|}{2}$, it'll be much simpler.

Comment: @ArcticChar It's not the same, there it's with $0$ and here with $x$.

Comment: Well.... can you do a simple change $a_n \mapsto a_n -x$?

Comment: But @Xavi, how about let another sequence, $y_n=a_n-x$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I don't think about that, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$ and $L \neq 0$. Prove there is some $N$ such that $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n \geq N$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942879/suppose-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-a-n-l-and-l-neq-0-prove-there-is)